# Should DAL always return business objects in MVP

Tags: c#, .net, oop, ado.net, mvp

1. In Model View Presenter (`MVP`) pattern, it is said that our `DAL` always should returns business models. But let's say if I want to get just a number from database like the last `ClientID` (the latest clients ID) which is a string, should my `DAL` method returns a `ClientInfo` object which has about 10 other fields as well like `ClientName`, `Address` etc.?
2. If I want to get a list of business objects from my `DAL`, is it acceptable to do it as follows or better to get a `DataTable` from `DAL` and then in the applications `BLL`, converts it a `List`?

   ```
   public List<Employee>  GetNewEmployees()
   {
       string selectStatement = "SELECT Employee.Emp_ID, Employee.Initials + ' ' + Employee.Surname AS Name,...";

       using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(db.GetConnectionString))
       {
           using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, sqlConnection))
           {
               sqlConnection.Open();
               using (SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
               {
                   List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
                   while (dataReader.Read())
                   {
                       list.Add (
                       new EpfEtfMaster { 
                           EmployeeID = (int) dataReader ["emp_id"],
                           EmployeeName = (string) dataReader ["Name"],
                           AppointmentDate = (DateTime) dataReader["appointment_date"],                                   
                       });                            
                   }
                   return list;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of an opinion based question, but ill go ahead and answer because i think its important.

1. If you have multiple accesses to your DB just to query your `ClientID`, then it is valid IMO not to allocate a whole `ClientInfo` object as it is redundant and there is no need for the whole extra allocation when you only need a `int/string`. Although if you do see yourself starting to add more than 1 property (Lets say you need to get a `ClientID` and an `Address`) then you should transform your return value to a `ClientInfo`. It really depends on the scenario.
2. Again, this is MO. I would let my DB return a `DataTable` as i dont want my `Data Access Layer` to have anything to do with my `Data Object Model`. If one day i desire to change it, i dont want it to be a cross cutting concern and refactor every part of the program. Instead, i would let an intermediate class take care of transforming the `DataTable` to my `DOM`. That way, only one place has to know a change has been made and i only need to refactor one place in my code. I would strongly suggest looking into [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org) as that intermediate layer for your application.

Comment: I would say that the conversion of the `DataTable` to the `BusinessObject` is an implementation detail of the DAL. It is IMO definitely **not** part of the Data Object Model (or Business Layer, or Domain Layer, or whatever you call it).

Comment: This is a philosophical argument :), but i believe the DAL should have knowledge of accessing the specific data source it is ment to access and no more. Although if you use `AutoMapper` to abstract away the transformation of the DB objects to your DOM, then it may be fine to do so in your DAL, as you are not forcing it to know how your DOM are built.